# why I couldn't makes points shown on bokeh map in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, geospatial, bokeh

I'm trying to plot some datapoint on a map in Bokeh but somehow nothing shows up, only the map background.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML, display
%matplotlib inline
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Lat': [40.7260,40.7209], 'Lon': [-73.991,-74.0507], 'Count': 1})
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()
from bokeh.tile_providers import STAMEN_TERRAIN

x_range, y_range = ((-8242000,-8210000), (4965000,4990000))
plot_width  = int(750)
plot_height = int(plot_width//1.2)

def base_plot(tools='pan,wheel_zoom,reset',plot_width=plot_width, plot_height=plot_height, **plot_args):
p = figure(tools=tools, plot_width=plot_width, plot_height=plot_height,
    x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, outline_line_color=None,
    min_border=0, min_border_left=0, min_border_right=0,
    min_border_top=0, min_border_bottom=0, **plot_args)
p.axis.visible = False
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
return p    
p = base_plot()
p.add_tile(STAMEN_TERRAIN)
p.circle(x=samples['Lat'], y=samples['Lon'], **options)
show(p)
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

The plot ranges are in Web Mercator units:

```
((-8242000,-8210000), (4965000,4990000))
```

But the data points in your `sample` DataFrame are in lat/lon units. You can either:

- add an "extra range" in lat/lon units (that match up!) and have `p.circle` reference the extra range instead of the default range.
- Convert your circle coordinates to Web Mercator

The latter is probably easier. [This page](http://www.neercartography.com/latitudelongitude-tofrom-web-mercator/) has a function that can do the conversion. Using it, you'd get

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({
    'easting': [-8236640.443285105, -8243286.216885463], 
    'northing': [4972010.345629457, 4971261.231184175]
})
```

Updating your code to use this:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.tile_providers import STAMEN_TERRAIN

samples = pd.DataFrame({
    'easting':  [-8236640.443285105, -8243286.216885463],
    'northing': [4972010.345629457, 4971261.231184175]
})

x_range, y_range = ((-8242000,-8210000), (4965000,4990000))
plot_width  = int(750)
plot_height = int(plot_width//1.2)

def base_plot(tools='pan,wheel_zoom,reset',plot_width=plot_width, plot_height=plot_height, **plot_args):
    p = figure(tools=tools, plot_width=plot_width, plot_height=plot_height,
        x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, outline_line_color=None,
        min_border=0, min_border_left=0, min_border_right=0,
        min_border_top=0, min_border_bottom=0, **plot_args)
    p.axis.visible = False
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    return p
p = base_plot()

p.add_tile(STAMEN_TERRAIN)

p.circle(x=samples['easting'], y=samples['northing'], size=20, color="red")

output_file("map.html")
show(p)
```

yields this plot:

[image]

Comment: thank you @bigreddot! A newbie question on map, is it possible to not use web mercator in defining the range, and directly use lat and lon in plotting?

Comment: That's not currently supported but perhaps could be part of new development. Feel free to open an issue on GitHub to discuss https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: thanks for the patient reply! I somehow couldn't make toWebMercator(sample['Lat'],sample['Lon']) work on entire columns of data frame, only individual rows. it returns error  __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

do i need to tweak some part of the formula?

Comment: The linked function was just meant to be quick and illustrative of the task. If you need something more comprehensive for handling arrays, etc, perhaps [Cartopy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/index.html) would be more suited.